# How would I be able to get the average from the list and print it as an output along with the toal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list = ['Monday:21', 'Tuesday:6', 'Wednesday:8', 'Thursday:18', 'Friday:16', 'Saturday:4', 'Sunday:10', 'Monday:8', 'Tuesday:23', 'Wednesday:10']
days_dict = {}
for entry in mondayCalls:
    day = entry.split(":")[0]
    count = int(entry.split(":")[1])
    print (day)
    print (count)
    if day in days_dict:
        days_dict[day] += count
    else:
        days_dict[day] = count

print (days_dict)

while days_dict:
    Day = input("What day would you like total and average for? ")
    #for day in days_dict():
    if Day == "Monday":
        print("The total for the day you selected = " + str(days_dict['Monday']))
    elif Day == "Tuesday":
        print("The total for the day you selected = " + str(days_dict['Tuesdayy']))
    elif Day == "Wednesday":
        print("The total for the day you selected = " + str(days_dict['Wednesday']))
    elif Day == "Thursday":
        print("The total for the day you selected = " + str(days_dict['Thursday']))
    elif Day == "Friday":
        print("The total for the day you selected = " + str(days_dict['Friday']))
    else:
        print("The day you selected is not available")
    break
```

I know there is probably a very easy way but ideally, I just want it to print:
The total and average for the day you selected is 41 and 20
or total = 41
average = 20

Comment: What do you mean average? Dicts have unique keys, which means you will have one value per day

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, in the dictionary, a count for the number of occurrences of the day can be maintained in a field and it can be increased by 1 for each occurrence of the day. It can be used to calculate the avg using normal avg formula.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question this could be a solution to your problem. I used a dictionary of lists.

```
list = ['Monday:21', 'Tuesday:6', 'Wednesday:8', 'Thursday:18', 'Friday:16', 'Saturday:4', 'Sunday:10', 'Monday:8', 'Tuesday:23', 'Wednesday:10']

days_dict = {}
for entry in list:
    day = entry.split(":")[0]
    count = int(entry.split(":")[1])
    if day in days_dict:
        days_dict[day].append(count)
    else:
        days_dict[day] = [count]

print (days_dict)

while days_dict:
    day = input("What day would you like total and average for? ")
    if day in days_dict:
        total = 0
        for n in days_dict[day]:
            total += n
        average = total / len(days_dict[day])
        print("The total and average for the day you selected is %d and %.2f" % (total, average))
    else:
        print("The day you selected is not available")
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want sum and average just for the day asked in input:

```
list = ['Monday:21', 'Tuesday:6', 'Wednesday:8', 'Thursday:18', 'Friday:16', 'Saturday:4', 'Sunday:10', 'Monday:8', 'Tuesday:23', 'Wednesday:10']
days_dict = {}
count = {}
for entry in list:
    day = entry.split(":")[0]
    sum = int(entry.split(":")[1])
    if day in days_dict:
        days_dict[day] += sum
        count[day] += 1
    else:
        days_dict[day] = sum
        count[day] = 1

Day = input("What day would you like total and average for? ")
if Day in ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]:
    print("The total and average for the day you selected is " + str(days_dict[Day]) + " and " + str(days_dict[Day]/count[Day]))
else:
    print("The day you selected is not available")
```